# Matching three columns on two sheets and pasting a specific column from match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets of purchase order information with a different PO per row that I need matched based on Column A, B and C being the same on each sheet. When a row is matched I need column R from sheet 1 to be pasted into sheet 2 column R.

Column A is a shipping code,
Column B the PO number,
Column C is the PO line number, and
Column R is the notes on the PO.

sheet 1 is the previous month and sheet 2 is the new month that may contain PO's from the previous month.

I am trying to pull these notes from the previous month over quicker as there are hundreds of rows per sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste this in column R of Sheet2 as an array formula. Do this by selecting the first empty cell in column R, pasting this into the formula bar and then holding CONTROL and SHIFT and hitting ENTER. Simply hitting ENTER will leave it as a regular formula and it will not work (it will return a blank every time). Once you've got it in one cell, you can drag it down to fill the column.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$R$2:$R$500, MATCH(Sheet2!A2&Sheet2!B2&Sheet2!C2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$500&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$500&Sheet1!$C$2:$C$500,0)),"")
```

Comment: Note that pnuts' answer below will also work and doesn't have the hassle of remembering to hit CONTROL, SHIFT and ENTER, but my answer doesn't require the extra columns. If you think you might forget, you should go with his version so you don't get false negatives. Also hundreds of rows should be fine, but if you start to get into the thousands, array formulas can take a bit longer to run.

Comment: I ran a modified version of this formula on a spreadsheet with 1800 rows of data and it was silky smooth

Answer (score 1):

Insert a left hand column in both sheets, and in A1 of both enter and copy down to suit:

```
=B1&C1&D1
```

in R1 of the sheet for the new month enter and copy down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet1'!A:S,19,0),"")
```

after adjusting `Sheet1` to the name of the tab for the old month.

Comment: I had to adjust to =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet1'!A:S,19,0),"") as what was column R had shifted, performs smooth